# How would one convert non-consecutive numbers to consecutive?

Tags: python

I would like to convert a set of non-consecutive numbers (1, 5, 6, 9, 10) to consecutive (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, I would like to convert them to start from one. For example if 5 is in second place, 5 would become 2.

Comment: then something like `numpy.arange(1,6)`?

Comment: You mean ***"rank the list of numbers"***. There are many duplicate solutions already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide more explanation, I assume that the last numshould be the last num in the Input tutple so you can do it with a simple List comprehension:

```py
nums = (1, 5, 6, 9, 10)

result = [num for num in range(1, nums[-1]+1)]
print(result)
```

### Result

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

### Using Itertools

```py
from itertools import count, islice


nums = (1, 5, 6, 9, 10)
x = islice(count(1), len(nums))
print(list(x))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

### Documentation

- [geeksforgeeks.org |python-itertools-islice/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools-islice/)
- [geeksforgeeks.org | python-itertools-count/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools-count/)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new tuple with the same number of elements starting from 1.

```
>>> t = (1, 5, 6, 9, 10)
>>> tuple(range(1, len(t)+1))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Also, to keep track of the new mapping you could use a dictionary.

```
>>> res = tuple(range(1, len(t)+1))
>>> dict(zip(t, res))
{1: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 9: 4, 10: 5}
```